# Theme files being pulled from sites/default/files rather than sites/<sitename>/files

Tags: theming, multi-sites

I'm pulling down a repository of a D8 multisite install and running it locally.

The sites are set `web/sites/default` and `web/sites/mysite`.  In the root of `sites` there is a `sites.php` which contains

```
$sites['mydomain.com'] = 'mysite';
```

In the web/sites/mysite directory there is a settings.php which has

```
$settings['file_public_path'] = 'sites/mysite/files';
```

however when I visit the local site in my browser I can see that files are being served from e.g. `/sites/default/files/2019-01/header-mysite.png` (I've added the `files` directory in both sites/default and sites/mysite).

The odd thing is that when I visit the site that is actually available on the web (which I am told is running from the same repo / branch as I have locally, the files are being loaded from e.g. `/sites/mysite/files/2019-01/header-mysite.png`

Can anyone advise how I should try to address this?  I tried adding my local url to `sites.php` but it didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: What do your `File system` settings say? `/admin/config/media/file-system`

Comment: thanks @prkos. In web/sites/mysite there are:
default.settings.php
settings.php
default.local.settings.php

each of which has `settings['file_public_path'] = 'sites/mysite/files';` but it doesn't seem to affect where the image is pulled from or the location that is shown in the Drupal Admin UI at admin/config/media/file-system